# Qt creator не компилирует программу

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Только начал программирование в QT creator. Установил прогу на Ubuntu 20.04 через Synaptic. Всё хорошо установилось, запустил creator, создал новый проект, в разделе Kits установил по дефолту Desktop, версию qt поставил пятую, проект сгенерировался, но после генерации выдает ошибки в только что сгенерированном коде (я ничего в нем не менял).

В main.cpp подчеркивает следующие строчки:

- `QApplication a(argc, argv);` Ошибка: "variable has incomplete type          "QApplication" "
- `MainWindow w;` . Ошибка: "unknown type name "MainWindow"

В файле mainwindow.cpp ошибки выдает вот в этих строчках:

- `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)`
- `MainWindow::~MainWindow()`

Ошибка для двух строчек одинаковая: "use of undeclared indetifier 'MainWindow'".

Также ошибка в файле mainwindow.h в двух строках:

- `class MainWindow : public QMainWindow` Ошибка: "expected class name"
- `Q_OBJECT` Ошибка: "incomplete result type 'QString' in function
  defenition".

Вот код файлов:
main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Если кто-то сможет помочь, заранее большое спасибо!

---

Вот код файла .pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs           deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
main.cpp \
mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Попробуйте собрать проект. Возможно после этого сообщения об ошибках исчезнут. Я наблюдал похожую картину при переносе проекта на другую машину. До сборки среда не знает, где что искать, и выдает некорректные сообщения.

Comment: Программа запускается?

Comment: При компиляции программа выдает те же самые ошибки

Comment: компилятор ругается на mainwindow.cpp

Comment: In constructor ‘MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)’:

Comment: потом идут ошибки

Comment: Перейдите в меню Справка->О модулях и там отключите ClangCodeModel - скорее всего просто некорректно работает парсер

Comment: Отключил, строки перестал подчеркивать, но при компиляции все равно выдает ошибки в файле mainwindow.cpp

Comment: Удалите сборку и скачайте с офсайта qt. Что-то где-то недонастроилось при установке, или проверьте пути к файлам и библиотекам самого Qt

Comment: При установке с оф сайта запускаю файл .run, который скачал с оф сайта и мне выдает следующие ошибки: /qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run: 1: ELF: not found
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run: 2: @#: not found
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run: 2: ��: not found
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run: 2: ��: not found
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.2.3-online.run: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Я переустановил прогу и все заработало. Спасибо огромное за помощь! Удачи!

Comment: Закрывайте вопрос. Это как то неправильно задавать вопрос про криво установленный софт